# Lucene query that eliminates xml tags in full text search

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, alfresco

In alfresco I need to write a lucene query such a way that It has to eliminate/exclude the xml tags from content while searching.

Example If a file try.xml is searched against the content, my search should not search for the xml tags.

```
try.xml
<sample>This is an example</sample>
```

If I give the search text as "sample" it should not return the file name "try.xml".
So how could I achieve this?

Edit

I have tried with the below query and no change.

```
@cm\:name:"try*" -TEXT:"<*>" +TEXT:"sample"
```

Whats wrong in the above query. I just tried to get the file name which starts with "try" and eliminating the text inside tag, and trying to search for text "sample".

Answer (score 1):

By default Alfresco treats XML files as plain text and indexes the xml tags as words, that's why they can be found via full text search. XML content is handled by the StringExtractingContentTransformer in Alfresco which converts text/xml to text/plain before indexing it.

To check which transformers are registered in your Alfresco installation you can check
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/mimetypes?mimetype=text/xml#text/xml

To prevent the indexing of xml attributes you have to write a special transformer which strips out the XML tags. See http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformations for an introduction in content transformation with Alfresco. The easiest way would be to integrate a command line utility that converts the xml file into text or you could implement a java class which does the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to do what you need, here's an excerpt of the [official documentation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search):

> Wild card queries Wildcard queries
>   using * and ? are support as terms and
>   phrases. For tokenized fields the
>   pattern match can not be exact as all
>   the non token characters (whitespace,
>   punctuation, etc) will have been lost
>   and treated as equal.

Basically, angle brackets are stripped out by default. You need to hack the indexing and query parsing processes in order to enable your wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just exclude the xml mimetype? (See http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Finding_nodes_by_content_mimetype for the syntax)

I guess you might want to exclude html too (so you'd exclude text/html and text/xml), that'd prevent you getting any nodes in your results that contain xml tags.